# What happens if we ignore result of new object?

Tags: java, constructor

I want to know what happens if create an object as:

```
new String("Hello World!");
```

and do not store the result in a reference variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing.

You create an object which will be garbage collected as no references to it exist.

The compiler could also decide to optimize it out in `-server` VM mode as this is "dead code".

Comment: Its worth noting that its still useful sometimes, for instance quickly creating a thread `new Thread(runnableObj).start();`

Comment: I'm not saying it's not useful sometimes. I'm talking only about the case the OP has specified.

Comment: And I'm not criticizing you, but rather adding information to your answer :P

Comment: Does it creates problem in my program?

Comment: I thought it would be a problem as Netbeans IDE highlights the code

Comment: @Madeyedexter It does because the code is not needed and the compiler will probably remove it. This will definitely not create a problem in your program however. It is (almost) the same as assigning this string to a reference and not using the reference afterword.

Answer (score 1):

Object is created and then Garbage collected later on.

If the code is executed multiple times I guess it will be removed by the JIT compiler